# Errors while reading a text file

Tags: c++, matlab

I have a problem with reading a text file in c++ and I can't figure out what is wrong. I need to read few complex numbers from file and do some calculations using matlab functions. So before that I compiled matlab library and included them to my project. I tested them and it works correctly. But when I added a few lines of code for reading data from file I get some errors:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
#include "spectrum.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0);
    spectrumInitialize();
    cout<<"Initialization success"<<endl;


    double input[4] = {10,20,30,40};
    mxArray *x_ptr, *x_ptr1;
    mxArray *y_ptr=NULL;
    mxArray *y_ptr1=NULL;
    double *y;
    double *y1;

    complex<double> com[256];

    ifstream myfile("dep.txt"); 

    double a = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<256;i++)
    {
        myfile >> a;
        com[i].real(a);
        myfile >> a;
        com[i].imag(a);
    }
    myfile.close();

    x_ptr1 = mxCreateDoubleScalar(256);
    x_ptr = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,256,mxCOMPLEX);
    memcpy((void *)mxGetPr(x_ptr), (void *) com,256*sizeof(complex<double>));

    mlfSpectrum_slice(1,&y_ptr,x_ptr,x_ptr1);

    y = (double*)mxGetPr(y_ptr);

    cout<<"Data: "<<input<<endl;
    cout<<"Result: "<<*y<<endl;

    mxDestroyArray(x_ptr);
    mxDestroyArray(y_ptr);

    spectrumTerminate();
    mclTerminateApplication();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to use fstream and ifstream too. Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?
By the way, I'm using Windows 7 32bit, Visual studio 2012 and Matlab R2012b.

Comment: What were the errors?

Comment: Looks like some of the matlab generated c files contain calls to functions defined in other matlab generated c files, which you haven't included in your build. Try and find which c file contains the definition for something like CrtDbgReportW(...) and make sure you're building it and linking the generated object with your final image.

Comment: Wild guess: Are you trying to link a debug build of the Matlab library to a release build of your own project? `_CrtDbgReportW` is only in the debug versions of the VC runtime, so if you compiled the Matlab library with the `_DEBUG` macro but link it against a non-debug runtime library, this error would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have a linkage problem.  The linker can't find the function CrtDbgReport. This is a Microsoft debug function.  It is all about writing debug messages using OutputDebugString API. Microsoft lib is kernel32.lib - so have you linked with that? Specifically it is looking for the Unicode version, that's the W on the end: CrtDbgReportW.  So you must have set a Unicode build somewhere.  ie #define UNICODE.

Is your lib maybe NOT using Unicode.

Another possibility is you are linking against debug matlab lib but you are building a release version of your program.  Or vice versa.